# What method should i use to find the type of pattern from 2 input arrays?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to ask about the method of solving a case I ran into. I have data with various variations with each index interrelated.

Data Example:

```
1 :
x1 = [ 'S' , 'M' , 'L', 'XL', 'XXL']
x2 = [ 10 , 30 , 20, 30, 20]
pattern = A

2 :
x1 = [ 'H' , 'X' , 'A', 'DL', 'AXL']
x2 = [ 10 , 40 , 10, 30, 10]
pattern = G

3 :
x1 = [ 'SS' , 'AM' , 'L', 'XL', 'SXL']
x2 = [ 90 , 30 , 30, 50, 10]
pattern = B
.
.
.
.
.
(n data)
```

- x1 -> type of clothes
- x2 -> qty of clothes
- pattern = the result ( A, B, C, D, E, F, G)

Altogether I have about 10,000 data with a pattern like that and I want to find the formula (r) using x1 array and x2 array. What method or algorithm can I use or what kind of solution exists for this case?

Comment: could you please rewrite question such that it become easy to understand.

Comment: this general case should be done by multi-classification algorithm, but in my case, the input  is not just one data, but an array.

so basically, if i'am input this array
x1 = [S, M, L, XL, XXL]
x2 = [ 10 , 30 , 20, 30, 20]

the result should be one of this type pattern ( A, B, C, D, E, F, G) according a similar pattern on the training data.